# Grant permission for only specific sh file with visudo

Tags: php, shell, sh, sudo, visudo

I want to run an sh script from php.
For this, i need to open visudo file:

sudo visudo

With this:

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

It works!

But I dont want to enable all command, just a specific sh script.
So i changed it to:

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /www/......./truncatefiles.sh
```

The path is correct, but shell_exec (from php) returns: sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
And the command wont run.
If the visudo line is same as my first example.

What can be the problem?

Comment: https://www.garron.me/images/2012-05/sudo-sudoers-make-me-sandwich.png

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bad idea cause it can create a potential security issue.

But if you still want to do so, 
you can keep `www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /www/......./truncatefiles.sh` and at the same time comment out the line that contain `Defaults    requiretty` in `/etc/sudoers` (**always** with visudo to avoid errors).